# Javascript isn't being called by submit button in HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

For some reason my javascript won't execute when my submit button is pressed. It's supposed to leave an error message beside two textfields for a user's name and email address if they are empty, but it's not and I can't figure out why. Normally, when the two boxes are filled, the submit would go to a php page which sends an email. Any suggestions or help with fixing my javascript problem will be greatly appreciated.

This is my javascript:

```
//my javascript function
<script type='text/javascript'>
function validate_form()
{
        $('span.error_message').html('');
        var success = true;
        $("#validate_form input").each(function()
        {
            if($(this).val()=="")
            {
                $(this).next().html("* You must complete this field"); // the error message
                success = false;
            }
        });
        return success;
    }
</script>
```

and my form in html:

```
<form action=".....whatever....." method="POST" id="validate_form" onsubmit="return validate_form();">
    <ol>
        <li>
            <span id="question">___ is your name? My name is Marie.</span>
            <input type="text" name="q1" id="q1" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <span id="question">___ are you from? I'm from Paris, France.</span>
            <input type="text" name="q2" id="q2" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <span id="question">Dave: ___ you like football</span>
            <p>
                <input type="radio" name="q6" value="1" id="q6_1" />
                <label for="q6_1">Are</label>

                <input type="radio" name="q6" value="2" id="q6_2" />
                <label for="q6_2">Do</label>

                <input type="radio" name="q6" value="3" id="q6_3" />
                <label for="q6_3">Does</label>

                <input type="radio" name="q6" value="4" id="q6_4" />
                <label for="q6_4">Is</label>
            </p>
        </li>
    <div id="username">
        <p>
            Before we begin, please enter your name and email:
            <br />
            <label for="user_name">Name: </label><input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" />
                <span class="error_message" style="color:#FF0000"></span>
            <br />
            <label for="user_email">Email: </label><input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" />
                <span class="error_message" style="color:#FF0000"></span>
        </p>
    </div>

        <p style="width: 242px; margin: auto;">
            &nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit your answers" id="but" />
        </p>
</form>
```

Edit: Fixed the problem with the javascript being called, but now the submit button isn't working even with the two textfields being filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#validate_form input")` - I don't see `validate_form` anywhere; you need to add it or just use: `$("input")`

Comment: Ah such a simple thing to miss, thank you! That has fixed that problem but another problem has arisen, now the form isn't submitting even if the textfields have been filled.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug for firefox would help you debug these types of jscript issues. You can also use the Error Console in Firefox if you dont want to install firebug.